# C# OracleCommand: Problem with Umlauts äöü

Tags: c#, oracle, encoding, oraclecommand

I call this function to write data to an Oracle database, which works.

```
private void callDB_Migration(string[] _values)
{
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("CHARTA_MIGRATION", oraCon))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        OracleTransaction transact = oraCon.BeginTransaction();
        cmd.Transaction = transact;

        // Parameter clearen
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        try
        {
            // Values übergeben
            cmd.Parameters.Add("i_PersNummer", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = _values[0];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("i_Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = _values[1];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("i_Vorname", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = _values[2];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("i_Geburtsdatum", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = _values[3];

            // function CALL
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            cmd.Transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

But in some columns in the database, the umlauts are not stored:

```
Gnther, Jrgen
```

Can I somehow pass an encoding format to `OracleCommand`?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10749/ch2charset.htm#i1006750

Comment: _"which works"_ - what does this mean? Do you mean calling it another way outside .NET preserves the umlauts and there's a problem with sending umlauts from C#? Or do you just mean that it gets called, but there are no umlauts?

Comment: by "which works" I mean that it writes to the database. The string array _values ​​has the correct values ​​with umlauts, I checked that in debugmode. The problem is that the umlauts no longer exist in the database. For example, Jürgen becomes Jrgen.

Comment: So if you use whatever DB admin software there is for Oracle, can you write values with umlauts there if you manually call the procedure? What character set does your database use?

Comment: I can't write values with umlauts if i manually call the procedure. 

The Characterset of the DB is AL32UTF8. In C# i use Encoding.Default. Mayb i should try another Encoding here. ^^,

Comment: @Trafel the problem is using `Varchar2` instead of a Unicode type like `nvarchar2`. C# strings are Unicode, just like Java, JavaScript and more. There's no encoding involved. `varchar2` is *not* a Unicode type. Unicode strings, from any language, will have to be converted to the non-Unicode field's codepage using whatever codepage/encoding the *Oracle client* thinks is used. Oracle's own client is ... quirky (and bloated), and can use the ORACLE HOME encoding instead of the field's encoding.

Comment: @Trafel which Oracle client are you using? Which version? How are you connecting? It matters. You can control encoding conversion from the connection. At some point there were two different clients, ODP that worked through Oracle HOME and a "thin" client. Now there's only Oracle.ManagedAccess for .NET Framework and Oracle.ManagedAssess.Core for .NET Core. These are still quirky (eg no real async methods) which is why third-party clients are so popular.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It works with nvarchar2. Thank you for the explanation which makes sense.

Comment: @Trafel the situation doesn't - I encountered the same problem in 2004. We ditched ODP with its 300MB size for Devart's tiny drivers which were infinitely faster and *didn't* have conversion problems. You can control automatic conversion from Unicode to the server's locale through connection settings. In SQL Server and Devart's client this is on by default. In the Oracle client it's off. That's why I asked about the connection string

Answer (score 0):

When we works with multilingual data and special character which are not in English :- Always use `NVARCHAR2` or similar datatype as per requirement.

Please Refer the below links for more details

[5.Supporting Multilingual Databases with Unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96529/ch5.htm)

[6.Supporting Multilingual Databases with Unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e10729/ch6unicode.htm)

Comment: 10 years ago, we have converted our Oracle database to AL32UTF8 character set. Since then, we never ever had an issue with special characters, emojis etc anymore. And we simply use VARCHAR2, not NVARCHAR2.

Comment: agreed but we don't convert to that then. Sometime it is not in your hand then we have to use nvarchar